# What is the purpose of LIFO memory allocation with an array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, alloc

```
 #define ALLOCSIZE 10000 /* size of available space */

 static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE]; /* storage for alloc */
 static char *allocp = allocbuf; /* next free position */

 char *alloc(int n) /* return pointer to n characters */
 {
     if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n) { /* it fits */
         allocp += n;
         return allocp - n; /* old p */
     } else /* not enough room */
           return 0;
 }

 void afree(char *p) /* free storage pointed to by p */
 {
     if (p >= allocbuf && p < allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE)
         allocp = p;
 }
```

So far, what I have understood is that the purpose of memory allocation is to keep the program efficient. Wouldn't declaring an array allocbuf take up all of that space and defeat the purpose? I sincerely thank anyone who answers.

Comment: Your code doesn't have any LIFO memory allocation, it's just allocating it all from the beginning.

Comment: The only "purpose" here is to keep the code simple.  This is very dangerous code.

Answer (score 1):

These functions serve as array allocators, but instead of using new memory, they use and reuse this large allocbuf, which is in the static segment and does not need usual allocation.

This is LIFO because only the last allocated storage is freed by `afree()`, but this needs cooperation from the client code in specifying `p` corresponding to the latest allocated storage.

As of your question, well it's faster to allocate from the static segment of the program than using `new`.